# Error in res values string "Locale it is missing translations for"

Tags: android

In my project I am getting an error that can't allow me to compiling.
It is reported, as an example:
**Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
Locale it is missing translations for: foo, htmlsource1, htmlsource_old values-it   /Android_coll/res line 1 Android Lint Problem**

" foo, htmlsource1, htmlsource_old " are old string that now are not any more in the in res->values-it folder.
To be more specific they are no longer present in the whole project

I've tried:

- close and open the project.
- close and open Eclipse (indingo)
- clean the project (project-> clean)
- copy the file string.xml from the folder values and copy it to the folder values-it

but i still have the same error message.

thanks
marco

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had this same problem when I updated to the 4.0 SDK.  The problem was with Android Lint.  If you go to project properties->Android->Lint Error Checking and change the severity of "Missing Translation" to be something other than Error, you should be able to build now.

Comment: I solved this way.
In folder Res i create e new folder Values-fr, the i copied the contents of the folder Values-it in values-fr. 
And everything works again. Then i delete the folder values-fr

Answer (score 5):

My solution is in 'Android Tools' -> 'Clean Lints Markets'

Before you can 'Run Lint' again  from Android Tools, error go away.